# Merging dictionaries optimization in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I want to optimize my code that merges two dictionaries in such a way that the values are joined in a list. If the key is not is common, the respective value in the list is None.

For example: `{k:v1 , k': v} {k:v2, k'': w}` are merged in `k':[v,None], {k:[v1,v2],  k'':[None, w]]}` .

Note that the order is important: I want all the values with None as the second element at the beginning of the dictionary, followed by the mixed ones, and at the end the ones with None as first element.

My code is working, but there is definitely a smarter way to do the same thing, since I am doing three for loops to achieve this result. Any idea how to optimize this function?

```
def MergeDictionary(dict1, dict2):
    dict3 = {}

    for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
        if k1 not in dict2:
            dict3[k1] = [v1, None]

    for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
        for k2, v2 in dict2.items():
            if k1 == k2:
                dict3[k2] = [v1, v2]

    for k2, v2 in dict2.items():
        if k2 not in dict1:
            dict3[k2] = [None, v2]

    return dict3
```

Comment: @KellyBundy what do you mean? My code works, I just want to optimize it.

Comment: If you mean my first comment: `{k:v1 , k': v} {k:v2, k'': w}` gives a syntax error, it's not valid Python, can't be used for testing. If you meany second comment, you fixed the description now so that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Concerning speed, I would say the solution is already good</strike> (actually not - the second loop is just wrong, I see that now), but the code could be simpler. It could also really support more dictionaries.

For two dictionaries, you can simply do this:

```
def merge_dicts(d1, d2):
    all_keys = set(d1) | set(d2)
    return {
        key: [d1.get(key), d2.get(key)]
        for key in all_keys}
```

To support more dictionaries, you can change it to something like this:

```
from itertools import chain

def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    all_keys = set(chain.from_iterable(dicts))
    return {
        key: [d.get(key) for d in dicts]
        for key in all_keys}
```

---

As for the problems in the original code, this:

```
        for k2, v2 in dict2.items():
            if k1 == k2:
                dict3[k2] = [v1, v2]
```

should at least be replaced with this, which does the same thing much faster:

```
        if k1 in dict2:
            dict3[k1] = [v1, dict2[k1]]
```

Comment: I thought of something like this, but in this case the order is not the right one. I don't know if ordering it afterwords is more efficient than doing it while building the dictionary,

Comment: OP's code may not be as efficient as she would like but it does generate the required output. Neither of the two suggestions here generate the correct/required output

Comment: The order of *values* is here correct. Keeping the order of *keys* makes no sense to me when merging dictionaries, so I'm not going to write that, but the union of sets could be replaced with a unique merge which keeps the order, if that is desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a dictionary comprehension by iterating on the union of keys sorted based on their presence in either dictionary:

```
d1 = {"k":"v1" , "k1": "v"}
d2 = {"k":"v2",  "k2": "w"}

d3 = { k:[d1.get(k),d2.get(k)] 
       for k in sorted({*d1,*d2},key=lambda k:(k in d2)-(k in d1) }

print(d3)
{'k1': ['v', None], 'k': ['v1', 'v2'], 'k2': [None, 'w']}
```